# Find asp controls added in runtime from server side by id that contatins string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I want to perform some actions on label click in client-side.
So i have a view:

```
<telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="rmpRightBar">
                        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="rpvHelpDetails">
                            //some code
                        </telerik:RadPageView>
                        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="rpvSearchDetails">
                            <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblSearchResult">
                            </asp:Table>
                        </telerik:RadPageView>
                    </telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

And code-behind where I add label in runtime to my view table:

```
private void SearchResultShow(IEnumerable<HelpModel> helpCollection)
    {
        var helpResultRow = new TableRow();

        foreach (var help in helpCollection)
        {
            var helpCell = new TableCell();
            var label = new Label();

            label.ID = "SearchResult_" + help.ID;
            label.Text = help.Title;
            helpCell.Controls.Add(label);

            helpResultRow.Cells.Add(helpCell);
        }

        tblSearchResult.Rows.Add(helpResultRow);
    }
```

Then I want to access my labels on client side and perform some actions on click.

JavaSctipt code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id*=SearchResult_]').click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
});
```

Since i have 2 pageviews i switch between them. And after i switch view my javascript doesn't work.

How can I access asp controls added in runtime by part of it's id using jquery?

Comment: Are you using RadAjaxManager or RadAjaxManagerProxy for the ajax call while switching between views?

Comment: RadAjaxManager

for now it's made in server side. like this

rmpRightBar.PageViews[1].Selected = true;

but it will be on client side. did not manage how to make it works yet

Comment: Take a RadScriptBlock in your page and put your javascript code inside it. Then Add its RadScriptBlock's Id in your ajax settings which you are using for switching between views.

Comment: thanks man, I added my Radscriptblock to RadAjaxPanel and it works now

Comment: Please upvote and mark as true my answer if it is working for you. It will increase my reputation and also inspire me to help in resolving such issues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a `RadScriptBlock` in your page and put your `javascript` code inside it. Then Add its `RadScriptBlock`'s Id in your `ajax settings` which you are using for switching between `views`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not what classes are for, but why not use them?

Instead of referencing your elements by ID, you can refer them by class. One caveat is to ensure you are not using classes for any style rule (which you can easily avoid by picking arbitrary names)

Comment: seems legit, but I needed to figure out how to make scripts work at all. now will thing about classes